# How to override the attr_protected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have STI implementation as follows:

```
class Automobile < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Car < Automobile
end

class Truck < Automobile
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :automobiles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :automobiles
end
```

I am creating a list of automobiles for a user. For each automobile, the UI sets the `type` field and the properties associated with the automobile.While form submission, the `type` field is ignored as it is a protected attribute.

How do I work around this issue? Is there a declarative way to `unprotect` a protected attribute?

**Edit:**
This is my current solution for the problem:
I override the `attributes_protected_by_default` private method in my model class.

```
class Automobile < ActiveRecord::Base
private
  def attributes_protected_by_default
    super - [self.class.inheritance_column]
  end
end
```

This removes the `type` field from the protected list.

I am hoping that there is a better way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
class Automobile < ActiveRecord::Base
private
  def attributes_protected_by_default
    super - [self.class.inheritance_column]
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but apparently Automobile.new(params[:automobile]) does not work in my create controller-action.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a helper method on User that instantiates the appropriate subclass:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.automobile_from_type(type)
    self.automobiles << case type
    when "Car"
      Car.new
    when "Truck"
      Truck.new
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Unknown automobile type: #{type.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
class AutomobilesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @automobile = current_user.automobile_from_type(params[:automobile][:type])
    if @automobile.update_attributes(params[:automobile]) then
      redirect_to @automobile
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

The code above is "safe": an attacker can't inject arbitrary text into your automobiles.type column. Your solution, while it works, has the disadvantage of enabling attacks.

Comment: My scenario is bit more complicated. I have three layers of nesting in my submission. I have to recreate the whole structure to perform this validation. I have resorted to adding a format validation for the `type` field in the Automobile class.