# Can nested attributes be used in combination with inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, nested-attributes

I have the following classes:

- *Project*
- *Person*
- *Person* > *Developer*
- *Person* > *Manager*

In the `Project` model I have added the following statements:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :people
accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
```

And of course the appropriate statements in the class `Person`. How can I add a `Developer` to a `Project` through the `nested_attributes` method? The following does not work:

```
@p.people_attributes = [{:name => "Epic Beard Man", :type => "Developer"}]
@p.people
=> [#<Person id: nil, name: "Epic Beard Man", type: nil>]
```

As you can see the `type` attributes is set to `nil` instead of `"Developer"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem few days ago. The inheritance column(i.e. `type`) in a STI model is a protected attribute. Do the following to override the default protection in your `Person` class.

**Rails 2.3**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

private
  def attributes_protected_by_default
    super - [self.class.inheritance_column]
  end
end
```

**Rails 3**

Refer to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325763/163203) suggested by [@tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland).

**Caveat:**

You are overriding the system protected attribute.

**Reference:**

[SO Question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527126/how-to-override-the-attr-protected)

Comment: note: this works for Rails 2.3, see my answer below for Rails 3

Comment: @tokland, I hadn't visited this question for sometime. I have updated my answer with a Rails 3 solution.

Comment: great. I'd write a simple `def self.attributes_protected_by_default`, but whatever.

Comment: @tokland, you are right over-riding the class method is easier. When I was testing that approach, as I had a funky object/class state in my irb session and the `super` call didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution for Rails3**: [attributes_protected_by_default](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/ClassMethods/attributes_protected_by_default) in now a class-method:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def self.attributes_protected_by_default
    super - [inheritance_column]
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: Make sure you put this near the top of the class, *before* any calls to `attr_protected`.  The first call to `attr_protected` will cause it to call whatever version of `attributes_protected_by_default` is currently defined, which will be the default version from AR unless you've overridden it by that point...

Answer (score 4):

Patches above did not work for me, but this did (Rails3):

```
class ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection
  def build_association(*options)
    if options.first.is_a?(Hash) and options.first[:type].presence
      options.first[:type].to_s.constantize.new(*options)
    else
      klass.new(*options)
    end
  end
end
```

Foo.bars.build(:type=>'Baz').class == Baz

Comment: This solution works for associations, but not for stand along STI object construction. I have updated my answer with a generic Rails 3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us using Mongoid, you will need to make the `_type` field accessible:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  attr_accessible :_type
end
```